# Moving the data between partitions in a table

Tags: sql-server, database, data-partitioning

There is one table with partition, where partition function and scheme is defined like below:

```
  CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION DateRangePF (CHAR(8))
    AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('20180101','20190101')

  CREATE PARTITION SCHEME DateRangePS 
    AS PARTITION DateRangePF TO (Y2018FG, Y2019FG);
```

There are lot of data into the partition with boundary value '20190101' and we decided to partition it into 4 parts with following boundary values and associated file groups:

> - '20190101' with file group Y012019FG,
> - '20190401' with file group Y042019FG,
> - '20190701' with file group Y072019FG,
> - '20191001' with file group Y102019FG.

Now, what could be the best strategy to switch the data from older single partition with boundary value '20190101' to these four partitions?

Comment: [duplicate post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223529/moving-the-data-between-partitions-in-a-table)